# Swift - Add and Remove UILabel on button tap

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel

I've created two buttons, One button to create a UILabel and other to delete the created UILabel.

On tapping Button1, I'm running a for-loop, to create four(4) UILabels and I'm able to do that.

On tapping Button2, I want to delete all the UILabels that I created with Button1.

Sidenote: I don't want to hide the UILabels as the variable 'noOfLabels' can be increased from 4 to 15 or any other number as per requirement.

Here is what I've tried.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var myLabel : UILabel!
   var noOfLabels = 4
    @IBAction func addButton(_ sender: Any) {

    if(myLabel != nil && !myLabel.isHidden)
    {
        myLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    print("AddLabel button is Tapped")
    var yval = 0
    for i in 0...noOfLabels
    {
        myLabel = UILabel()
        myLabel.frame =  CGRect(x: 30, y: 200 + yval, width: 90, height: 50)
        myLabel.text = "Hello \(i)"
        view.addSubview(myLabel)
        yval += 80
    }
}

@IBAction func removeButton(_ sender: Any) {

    print("Remove button is Tapped")
    myLabel.removeFromSuperview()

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

With the above code, I'm able to remove just one label.

I need help removing all UILabel on tapping Button2

Comment: Do you want to add only one new label while pressing the add button? Do you want to remove one last label or remove all label while you press delete button?

Comment: You can only delete the last label since myLabel points to the last one. Please set 4 labels in an array instead of changing myLabel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you have reference just for last created instance of label and you remove just this one. You need array of labels in order to be able to remove all created labels.

```
var labels = [UILabel]()
```

then when you need to create new label, also append it to this array

```
@IBAction func addButton(_ sender: Any) {

    labels.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
    labels.removeAll()

    for i in 0...noOfLabels {
        let newLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 200 + (i * 80), width: 90, height: 50)) // <--- new instance
        newLabel.text = "Hello \(i)"
        view.addSubview(newLabel)
        labels.append(newLabel) // <--- appending to an array
    }
}
```

Then when you need to remove all labels from their superview, just iterate through the `labels` array

```
@IBAction func removeButton(_ sender: Any) {
    labels.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
    labels.removeAll()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

define

```
var labelList: [Label] = []
```

in

```
addButton(_ sender: Any) {
...
view.addSubview(myLabel)
labelList.append(myLabel)
...
}


@IBAction func removeButton(_ sender: Any) {

print("Remove button is Tapped")
for i in 0...noOfLabels
{
    labelList[i].removeFromSuperview()

}
labelList = []
```